# Pygame, Python 3.8.3 and Alien Invasion

Tags: python, pygame

Like so many on here I am trying to get the Alien Invasion game going.  But I cannot get Pygame to work, it comes up when I execute the program, but it is blank, black screen, and no ship.  I have tried using a previous version of Pygame (dev6 right now), but again to no avail. The code below is verbatim from the book (Python Crash Course).  Here is the code:

```
import sys
import pygame
from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship

class AlienInvasion:
    """Overall class to manage game assets and behavior"""
    def __init__(self):
        """initialize the game, and create game resources"""
        pygame.init()
        self.settings = Settings()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
            (self.settings.screen_width, self.settings.screen_height))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")
        self.ship = Ship(self)
        # Set the background color
        self.bg_color = (230, 230, 230)
    def run_game(self):   
        """Start the mainloop for tha game"""   
        while True:
            # Watch for keyboard and mouse events
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    sys.exit()
        # Redraw the screen during each pass.
        self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)
        self.ship.blitme()          
        # Make the most recent drawn screen visible.
        pygame.display.flip()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Make a game instance and run the game
    ai = AlienInvasion()
    ai.run_game()
```

This is the settings.py file:

```
class Settings:
    """A class to store all settings for Alien Invasion"""
    def __init__ (self):
        """Initialize the game settings"""
        # Screen Settings
        self.screen_width = 1200
        self.screen_height = 800
        self.bg_color = (230, 230, 230)
```

and the ship.py file:

```
import pygame
class Ship:
    """A class to manage the ship"""
    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        """Initlialize the ship and its starting position"""
        self.screen = ai_game.screen
        self.screen_rect = ai_game.screen
        self.screen_rect = ai_game.screen.get_rect()
        # load the ships image and get its rect
        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/ship.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        # start each new ship at the bottom center of the screen
        self.rect.midbottom = self.screen_rect.midbottom
    
    def blitme(self):
        """Draw the ship at its current location"""
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

I am running on windows 10

I am truly stumped as I have seen so many "solutions" that don't work, and the author of the book knows there is a problem, but his solution did not work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a matter of [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). You have to draw the scene and to update the display in the application rather than affter the loop:

```py
class AlienInvasion:
    # [...]

    def run_game(self):   
        """Start the mainloop for tha game"""   
        while True:
            # Watch for keyboard and mouse events
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    sys.exit()

            #-->| Indentation

            # Redraw the screen during each pass.
            self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)
            self.ship.blitme()          
            # Make the most recent drawn screen visible.
            pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: I am not sure where and what I am supposed to indent?  And thank you for the help

Comment: oh my god, I just figured it out.  Thanks so much.  I cannot believe it was that simple.  The code in the book is not indented like that.  Thanks again, really appreciate your time.  cheers.

Comment: @Andrew Thank you. You're welcome.